# Binding a property using @Value to a closure in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, properties, binding

I have a Grails plugin (4.0.1) where I'm trying to bind properties in a Grails agnostic way.

My datasource in runtime.groovy is as follows;

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = 'none'
    pooled = true
    username = "root"
    password = ""
    dialect = UTF8MySQL5InnoDBDialect.name
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    properties {
        jmxEnabled = false
        initialSize = 5
    }
    remoteDataSources {
        disabled = false
        urlGenerator = { String host ->
            "jdbc:mysql://${host}:3306/myDb?characterEncoding=utf8"
        }
    }
}
```

Access the config above works fine using Grails methods;

```
def dbConfig = grailsApplication.config.dataSource
String dbUrl = dbConfig.urlGenerator(thisHost)
```

But when I try and use a Grails agnostic approach (Spring Boot), I cannot get it to bind;

```
@Value('${dataSource}')
private Map dataSource
```

Accessing individually seems to work;

```
@Value('${dataSource.remoteDataSources.disabled}')
private boolean disabled
```

But the main issue is with the closure;

```
@Value('${dataSource.remoteDataSources.urlGenerator}')
private Closure urlGenerator
```

Results in;

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'groovy.lang.Closure': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible but just in case anyone has any ideas of a better approach or workaround, that would be great!

Comment: For sure, I actually understand why the error is being thrown. No conversion strategies exist for a Closure type. 
What I'm trying to figure out is, whether someone knows if this is achievable at all?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work, so I worked around it by using the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation instead.

I applied the following guide to my similar case;
https://guides.grails.org/grails-configuration-properties/guide/index.html

But noted the following observations that may help others;

- If you create the configuration class outside of the Grails directory structure, make sure to register the bean in resources.groovy
- You must use a lowercase value for the prefix `datasource` or you will get an error. Although this will still bind with the `dataSource` configuration in your properties.
- The Closure config cannot be nested and must be at the top level so that it's type can be specified as such.

So for example;

```
dataSource {
    username = 'root'
    password = ''
    // etc
    properties {
        jmxEnabled = false
        initialSize = 5
    }

    disabled = false
    urlGenerator = { String host ->
        "jdbc:mysql://${host}:3306/myDb?characterEncoding=utf8"
    }
}
```

My Class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
class DataSourceConfiguration {

    String username
    String password

    Map<String, String> properties

    boolean disabled
    Closure urlGenerator

}
```

This was my experience at the time of writing using Grails 4.0.1. I won't mark this as the answer (as it doesn't directly answer the question) but I wanted to contribute it in case it helps others who where in the same situation as me where a workaround was satisfactory.